# LibGdx resume delay

Tags: java, android, libgdx, delay, resume

The problem is when my game is hidden, there is a delay when it's resumed. Each time game is resumed it takes longer. This happens on any screen set including splash screen where assets are being loaded. There is no difference in delay when game is resumed to game screen or splash screen, or menu screen. That means there is no problem with a lot of assets being loaded. I tested other game called "Cut the Rope 2" and there is no such delay, game resumes immediately.

I would like to add, that when I launch application first time, there is no such delay it jumps straight away to splash screen. Also when I press back button, it restarts the whole application and there is no delay also. That means that there is only a delay when application is resumed and there is no delay at all when application is launched first time or restarted.

UPDATE:

My problem is exactly like the one posted in the link below. Problem wasn't solved there. http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=11433&p=51515&hilit=resume+slow#p51515

So the problem is that this is called when my game resumes:

```
assetManager.finishLoading();
```

I didn't put that code in resume(). From the link above, I read that it's called automatically. When you press "Back Button" on tablet and then you resume the game, it takes time to launch application. If you press "Lock Button" and then you resume the game it launches game immediately but it freezes. So there are two different behaviors according to the button which was pressed. I would prefer to launch game immediately and not freeze but play my loading screen. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I guess you have some `Texture`s in your game right? So read this for some infos: (http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Textures#Managed_&_Unmanaged_(dynamic)_Textures_in_LibGDX). I am not sure but it could be, cause your `Texture`s get unloaded and as managed `Texture`s they are loaded automatically on `resume()`. This loading proccess will take some time. So even if you don'T unload/load them manually in pause/resume they are unloaded and so have to be reloaded automatically.

Comment: I do have textures as well as sounds. I also use AssetManager to load files and I don't unload them manually when application is hidden. If this is the case what you are saying. Then how can delay be prevented? Keep in mind that in other games, I tested "Defender 2" as well this problem doesn't occur. Game just launches without waiting more than 3 seconds. Also delay is not constant, it increases each time you resume my game. It starts from 1 second, then you need to wait 2 seconds and it keeps increasing.

Comment: And another thing to notice is that this happens even if it resumes to just a splash screen where there is only a logo and text. That shouldn't take long to load that. In comparison to Cut the Rope 2, it takes you immediately to the game map.

Comment: I'm testing more. And what I got so far is that after I commented batch.dispose in my MainMenu screen it takes now constant time to resume which is 5 seconds. But in my splash screen it still increases. That gives me so clues how to remove this increase. And it takes that much time probably because of size of the files and amount of them to reload. I have 25 textures to load. After I look more into it I will be able to justify if your answer solves my problem, but you pointed at important thing, so thank you.

Comment: Ok, after playing Cut the Rope 2, it still bothers me how is it, that it takes more time for it to load the files when you launch it first time and it also loads more additional files when you start the level, while in my case it takes less time to load them but it takes more time to load them on resume, while with that game it's immediate. Any clues why?

Comment: Now I measured and for my app it takes 8 seconds to load assets at the first launch and it takes 5 seconds for the Cut the Rope 2. But when you start the level in my case it takes 2 seconds and for the Cut the Rope 2 it takes 5 seconds. So it seems to be no difference in timing here, but still in resume difference is big. I need to go to uni right now, so after I come back I'll dig more into it. Maybe Cut the Rope 2 weights much less then my application and that's the case. My game weights 100 Mb.

Comment: If you load ALL your `Assets` on start up (i think thats the case) it will, ofc, take longer then if you load only, for example, `MenuAsset`s. But then if you load a level you only need to build it (place the objects or what ever), and you don't need to load more `Asset`s. So it is faster. If you `resume()` your `Game` while being in `SplashScreen` it is ofc as slow as in `GameScreen`, if you allready have all `Texture`s loaded. If you instead load only the once you need for the next `Screen` the `resume()` speed will depend on the `Screen`

Comment: So please tell us how and when do you load which `Asset`s? This can help to find a solution. Also please show us what you are doing in your `resume()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I updated info, so please read. In resume() method nothing happens. It's empty. In show() I use AssetManager.load() to load things and assign them to variables initialize them once they are loaded.

Comment: I tested another game to see if a game that weights more than mine can have the same problem. But it seems that game that weights around 230 MB, which is 130 more than mine, doesn't have any delay, you resume and it displays immediately the screen of the game. I noticed only that if you leave application untouched for a while, then it takes 5-6 seconds to resume. Game is called "CSR Classics"

Comment: I played a bit Cut the Rope 2 and what I see is, that each time screen is changed, first loading screen appears that loads assets. I'll try this approach so for each screen I have I'll load only assets that are needed for a specific one and assets that were loaded and are not needed I will dispose them.

Comment: I wanted to test some game that weights significantly more than mine. I played Thor The Dark World. It loads only twice in the game. For the global map and for the level. This is how I'm doing it and it resumes immediately for this game. It weights nearly 1 GB and it's much more complex than my game. It has got much more things happening on the screen. That stopped me from realizing mentioned idea above and it makes me think again what is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to call

```
Texture.setAssetManager(manager);
```

In this way AssetManager.finishLoading() will not be called automatically when game is resumed. Therefore it will not reload any assets. AssetManager.update has to be called manually.